# How to apply TemplateBinding to "Auto" height and width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, templatebinding

In resource dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="ControlFrame" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="2">
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <VisualBrush>
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="8, 2" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                           StrokeThickness="2"
                                           Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                           Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In C#:

```
TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
textbox.Width = 200;
textbox.Height = 200;
Style style = this.FindResource("ControlFrame") as Style;
textbox.Style = style;
canvas.Children.Insert(0, textbox);
```

I can get the dashed border properly.

[image]

If I wrap the **Textbox** into a **ContentControl** without giving the height and width of the **Textbox** like the following:

```
TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
Style style = this.FindResource("ControlFrame") as Style;
textbox.Style = style;
ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
cc.Content = textbox;
cc.Height = 200;
cc.Width = 200;
canvas.Children.Insert(0, cc);
```

The result is missed up:

[image]

I guess the reason is:

In Style, I use the following to set Width and Height of the border. They rely on the **TextBox**'s Width and Height.

```
Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
```

If I wrap the **TextBox** into a **ContentControl**, **TextBox**'s Width and Height are set to Auto and changed according to the **ContentControl**. But, the **Style** cannot get the exact Height and Width any more.

My question is:

Is there any way to let my **Style** display properly for a **TextBox** wrapped within a **ContentControl**. Since the **ContentControl** is draggable, I cannot set exact Height and Width to the inside **TextBox**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not explicitly setting the `Width/Height`, you will have to change your template bindings to `ActualWidth/ActualHeight`:

```
<VisualBrush.Visual>
   <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="8, 2" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
              StrokeThickness="2"
              Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
              Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}"/>
</VisualBrush.Visual>
```

Layout:(if I understand your question correctly)

```
 <Grid>
     <ContentControl >
        <TextBox BorderBrush="Red" Background="Blue" Style="{StaticResource ControlFrame}" />
     </ContentControl>
 </Grid>
```

`ActualWidth/ActualHeight` will return the rendered size of the control, `Width/Height` will returm NaN if its not explicity set elsewhere.